# What happens to reputation earned when question is migrated?

Tags: discussion, reputation, migration

I answered a certain question correctly on ***p-n-p transistors and doping*** in [**Phys.SE**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) and the answer was accepted and voted up. I got +25 reputation for that. Today I came to know that the question has been migrated to [**Electrical Engineering.SE**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) community. Side by side, I have lost 25 reputation for no valid reason. Are the events interlinked? Can the reputation be somehow gained back or is it lost forever?

Comment: I feel your pain, having lost a few hundred rep to migrations myself. There will be other questions to answer, however ;)

Comment: Though, I would like to point out that there *is* a valid reason: the question wasn't on-topic here on Physics but was on EE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can regain the migrated reputation by creating an account on EE.SE that is linked to your Phys.SE account.